# SUMIF using NOT ISDATE

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum across a range of  fields, but only if the cell contains a number, not a Date.

I would love to use something like SUMIF(A2:Z2,"!ISDATE()",A2:Z2)

But the criteria in SUMIF is incredibly dumb.  Is it possible that  there is a valid solution out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `=SUM(FILTER(A2:Z2,ISERROR(DATEVALUE(A2:Z2))))` where

- [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en) interprets the content as a date, if it would be auto-converted into a date when entered. Otherwise it throws an error.
- [`ISERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349?hl=en) returns True value if its input is an error
- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) narrows down the data set to those columns or rows where the condition holds.

Comment: I know this is old, but any way to do this when one is summing over a range of columns, and any arbitrary row could contain dates?